# Connecting ReactJs app to SpringBoot MVC/PostgresQL backend

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am developing a React app that needs to be connected to a backend server so that the user can login using Google OAuth, and then once that access token is granted, they are able to see the rest of the app. However, I am having a difficult time understanding just how to connect the front-end app to the backend. If someone could enlighten me on this, using SpringBoot MVC and PostgreSQL, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to communicate your FE(React) and your BE(SpringBoot MVC).

You can have REST endpoint on your Backend, and then try to communicate from your react application, you can use `[axios][1]`, [request](https://github.com/request/request) or the [native fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Then you can just make calls to the BE, and try to  read, update, delete or create information, you should read about CRUD.

The most common this days is build something like this:

```
(FE) <---> (BE) <---> (DB)
```

But I strongly recommend you to read more about:
- React SPA.
- REST, you can also read about SOAP or even GraphQL.
- CRUD.

You will found a lot of tutorials with very good examples of how to do it.

Hope this helps you to understand a little more what approach to use.